# I want to Run my php file depending on the client possibility

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php file called reportemail.php  file, And I have one drop down with 3 values like daily,weekly,monthly

If the client set time as daily I want to run the file(reportemail) and I want to send email every morning..and I want to do this is in localhost only,not in server.and I want this should be happen if the system is in shutdown mode also.

I already tried with cron.bat file it is working fine,but there manually I gave time..instead of giving manually I want to give dynamically.

Here is how I did in cron.bat file

```
E:\xampp\php\php.exe -f E:xampp/htdocs/custom/reportemail.php
```

And in reportemail.php file i have my email code and script code like this

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.reload();
    }, 5 * 60 * 1000);

    document.write(new Date());
</script>
```

Comment: Ok. Nice to know. Do you have any questions?

Comment: :) thanq can you please explain me what are all the possiblity ways to do that

Comment: pass as argument to cron file Eg: php reportemail.php 3

Comment: sorry i didn't get you can you please explain briefly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cron` is still the way to go here.  You just want to separate the scheduler from the scheduled events a little bit more.

Don't try to have the users create/modify the cron job scheduling itself.  Instead, schedule a universal cron job to execute at the narrowest time frame (daily).  That single job would:

- Check for user reports scheduled to run.
- Check when those reports were last successfully run and if it's time to do them again.
- Run the reports.

So instead of scheduling cron jobs, your users are simply saving a record to a database indicating when to run their reports.  For example, consider a table like this:

```
UserReports
----------
ID (PK)
UserID (which user)
ReportID (which report to run)
ScheduleID (which frequency - daily, weekly, etc.)
LastRunDate (date of the last successful run)
```

Any time the cron job executes, it would select from this table any records which meet the criteria:

- ScheduleID is daily and LastRunDate is 1+ days ago, or
- ScheduleID is weekly and LastRunDate is 7+ days ago, or
- ScheduleID is monthly and LastRunDate is 1+ month ago

Loop through the records which meet those criteria, run the reports, update the records with a new `LastRunDate` of today.

Comment: ok thats fine..if we want to do it in cron our system should be always  active rite?then only it will send email rite?

Comment: @user200: What do you mean "our system should be in active"?  Do you mean that the system needs to be *powered on* and *running*?  Then yes, yes it does.

Comment: ok if system is shutdown model also will  it possible to send mail?

Comment: @user200: If the computer running the reports is *powered off* then, no, it won't run the reports.  In general a computer needs to be *on* in order to do anything.  If I've misunderstood what you're saying, please clarify.

Comment: thanq for help,thanks a lot.